# Have cache folder cleared after each SVN update

Tags: caching, svn, twig

How can I use SVN to automatically clear the content of a folder "cache" after each `svn update` (or maybe `update` is the wrong command)?

The reason for which I need that is that I want an automatic way to update Twig cache on deploy: when cache is cleared Twig will recreate the cache which is what I want.

The problem with "update" is that eventually new files are added or modified, but files created by server are not "erased".

P.S:
**Deploy =** synchronizing the folder on server with SVN to latest trunk/tag.

Comment: you must to provide more details abt process - "deploy" is too broad

Comment: I want svn to clear content of a folder on each "update" using SVN functionality and not custom scripts. It is not too broad, I think people lately do not take time to read questions just to get stretch goals